# MYSQL - Using GROUP with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

So this statement started off without the join, it would simply lookup the product tables and group results by item_code.

```
SELECT a.item_code,
       a.price,
       b.v_no
FROM product a
JOIN variation b ON a.item_code = b.item_code
WHERE a.price>=2
GROUP BY a.item_code
```

Now that I have added the join I want to group by v_no but ONLY if data v_no exists. This is because not every item from the `product` table has a corresponding entry in the `variation` table. So group by `item_code` for 'normal' products, but group by `v_no` THEN `item_code` if a `v_no` exists.

The below does not work:

```
SELECT a.item_code,
       a.price,
       b.v_no
FROM product a
JOIN variation b ON a.item_code = b.item_code
WHERE a.price>=2
GROUP BY b.v_no,
         a.item_code
```

The `item_code` grouping remains but the `v_no` grouping is ignored.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: No none of these are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to consider all the product(s) (with/without variations), you will need to change to `LEFT JOIN`.
- For conditional Group By, you can use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function; it will consider the first non-null value for Grouping upon.

Try the following:

```
SELECT a.item_code,
       a.price,
       b.v_no
FROM   product a
       LEFT JOIN variation b
         ON a.item_code = b.item_code
WHERE  a.price >= 2
GROUP  BY COALESCE(b.v_no, a.item_code)
```

Comment: @Guesser Happy to help. Thanks :)